# If an <input> has a pattern attribute, is there value to also including the required attribute?

Tags: html, forms

If, for example, you have:

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="[a-z][a-z0-9]{2,7}">
```

does adding "required", as in:

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="[a-z][a-z0-9]{2,7}" required>
```

add any value or functionality?  Everything seems to operate the same, but I'm wondering if I missed some subtlety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Section 4.10.5.3.6. "The pattern attribute" of the HTML5 Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) the pattern is only checked if the input's value is the non-empty:

> If the element’s value is not the empty string, ... and the element has a compiled pattern regular expression but that regular expression does not match the entirety of the element’s value, then the element is suffering from a pattern mismatch.

So, to prevent the submission of the form with an empty value, the required attribute is (also) required (even if an empty string does not match the pattern).

Note: this also applies to the [HTML5 constraint validation API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript)

If the input is empty then *input*`.validity.valid` will be `true` and *input*`.validity.patternMismatch` will be `false` and unless the required attribute is also present, then *input*`.validity.valueMissing` will also be `false`.

*[fyi: As of this writing, the API is widely supported, although IE and Blackberry mess up some aspects]*

Answer (score 1):

In html5, "required: attribute is added to make the field mandatory. Otherwise it will throw an error on form submit.
And if you type any input value, pattern will validate accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but unless your pattern matches the empty string, having a pattern seems to have exactly that effect as well.

Comment: Yes as you say if you add a pattern it will surely ask for the input and validate accordingly, but required is something different and would be used during form submit making the form not valid. Just try with pattern alone and try form submit without entering any input value to your text field.